# Unable to create friendly url using kaminari and nested routes (rails 4.2.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I have a model called Book and the book `has_many` Pages(Page.rb - model). Basically, I am trying to recreate a book with contents and each page can be browsed using the `<%= link_to_next_page @pages, 'Next Page' %>` and 
the previous page helper methods. I am rendering just one page using `@pages = @book.pages.page(params[:page]).per(1)` as described on the kaminari github page. Also, I am using the friendly-id gem for both Book and Page models.

The url is getting rendered like this :-

```
localhost:3000/tutorials/create-a-book/pages/introduction?&page=1
```

and the next page link is like :-

```
localhost:3000/tutorials/create-a-book/pages/introduction?&page=2
```

I want the links to be displayed as :-

```
localhost:3000/tutorials/create-a-book/pages/introduction
```

and the next page like :-

```
localhost:3000/tutorials/create-a-book/pages/getting-started
```

I tried following the instructions given at [Kaminari Github Page - Creating friendly URLs and caching](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#creating-friendly-urls-and-caching) but was unable to understand it as I am not able to get my head around the routing part. I also searched the wiki but was unable to find anything related to the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Kaminari you can have

```
localhost:3000/tutorials/create-a-book/pages/introduction?&page=1
localhost:3000/tutorials/create-a-book/pages/introduction?&page=2
```

or

```
localhost:3000/tutorials/create-a-book/pages/introduction/page/1
localhost:3000/tutorials/create-a-book/pages/introduction/page/2
```

And that is all Kaminari can do for you. Kaminari can not guess how you want to name each page. And, as far as I know, Kaminari does not support named pages. (The "pages" that I refer to are the pages generated by the pagination. In your example, you have also a model named "Page" and I suggest you do not use the same name for two different things!)

To have what you want, you will have to route it properly ([guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)) and to link it in the views yourself.